# Matlab: plot lines parallel to the y axis

Tags: matlab, plot, yaxis

I want to plot all lines parallel to the y axis with x=10, 20,30,...,100

I wrote x as:

```
x=linspace(1,100,10);
```

and I try to plot in this way:

```
figure(1)
plot([x; x], [zeros(1, length(x))*min(ylim); ones(1, length(x))*max(ylim)],'r')
```

but this does not work well. How can I write y to plot such lines?

Comment: You say  x=10, 20,,...,100 but the `linspace(1,100,10);` create a vector with start value at 1. You should use  `linspace(10,100,10);` or better simply `10:10:100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but both your x-coordinates and your y-coordinates for the line ends are wrong. For x, you should use:

```
x = 10:10:100;
```

This generates `[10, 20, ..., 100]`. `linspace(1, 100, 10)` on the other hand generates 10 equally spaced values between 1 and 100 - which is somewhat different. To get the same values using `linspace` you would do `linspace(10, 100, 10)`.

For y, because you use `zeros`, the line only extends from zero to the upper y limit, rather than from the lower to the upper limit. Your call should instead be:

```
plot([x; x], repmat(ylim', 1, numel(x)), 'r')
```

This repeats the y-axis limits for each line, so the `i`-th line is drawn from `(x(i), ylim(1))` to `(x(i), ylim(2))`.

Comment: in this way the lines parallel to the y axis, have not  x = 10,20,30, ... 100 but have an x a little bigger about x=11,25...

Comment: That's because of how you use `linspace`. There's an error there too, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but might be what your looking for.

Use `XGrid`property to create (support) lines parallel to the Y-axis.

```
ax = axes;
ax.XGrid = 'on';
```

or for older Matlab versions

```
set(ax, 'XGrid', 'on')
```

(If you don't have the axes handle `ax`, you could use [`gca`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html))

This create lines at the current [`XTick`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html) of the plot. If you want to have the grid lines a specific range you have to change the XTick

```
ax.XTick = 0:10:100;
```

If you think that the lines are to weak (hard to see), you can turn up the grid alha value (default value is 0.5).

```
ax.GridAlpha = 1; %
```

or color it

```
ax.GridColor  = 'r'; % Set grid color to red
```

Comment: I though of using this too :) But it's not as flexible IMO.